# APNs push notification time IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, apns, alert

Let's assume a push notification is delayed for several minutes because the user's device bad network connection or a push notification with normal priority that is deferred because of the power-saving features.

By the time it is displayed on the phone, does it show as "Now" or "X min ago"?

What I really want to understand is whether it takes into account the timestamp that the push notification got from Apple APNs server or the time it is processed on the phone.